# create new column in dataframe from conditional multiplication by an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns; Date, Values1 and some column with dimensional data. Not relevant for this step, but I need the DataFrame to remain in the granularity as is.

Now I want to create an additional column, Values2, which is a multiplication of the value in Values1.
This multiplication is based on the month of Date and the factor is in an array (with a factor for each month)

```
d = {'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-23','2022-02-23', 
              '2022-02-27', '2022-03-05','2022-03-05','2022-04-02'], 
     'col2':['A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A'],
     'Value1': [1000, 1010, 900, 1000, 1000, 1010, 1000,1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
month_targets = [1.01,1.011,0.91,1.01,1.01,1.011,0.9,1.01,1.01,1.011,1.009,1.01]
```

How can I do this in the most efficient/pythonic way?
I don't think iterating over the month array and for each month iterate over the full dataframe would be ideal. so looking for a better way ;)

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `month_target` to a dictionary that maps months to target value; then `map` this dictionary to the months in `df`. Then multiply it with "Value1" column:

```
month_target_dict = dict(enumerate(month_targets, 1))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['Value2'] = df['date'].dt.month.map(month_target_dict) * df['Value1']
```

Output:

```
        date col2  Value1  Value2
0 2022-01-01    A    1000  1010.0
1 2022-01-01    B    1010  1020.1
2 2022-02-23    A     900   909.9
3 2022-02-23    B    1000  1011.0
4 2022-02-27    A    1000  1011.0
5 2022-03-05    A    1010   919.1
6 2022-03-05    B    1000   910.0
7 2022-04-02    A    1000  1010.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to merge the "factor" for each month into the existing array as a separate column. Then you can multiply the "month" from your existing `df` with that merged `factor` column.

```
factors = pd.DataFrame({'Month':range(1,13), 'Factor':month_targets})   
df['month'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64').dt.month
out = pd.merge(df, factors, how='left', on='month')
out['Value2'] = out['Value1'] * out['factor']
```

Comment: didn't think of doing it this way with the left join of the factors. that's a nice approach. thanks.